# How to carry a quadcopter on a bicycle?

Tags: cargo

I would like to take my quadcopter to interesting places. So I can do some flying and aerial photography etc.

Assuming a reasonably large quadcopter or drone - eg DJI Phantom, Cheerson CX-20, Syma X8C, or similar style. So about 350mm x 350mm square, and about 150 mm deep with the legs. It is possible to reduce this size a bit, by removing the propellers, legs, and camera, but I would rather not do that before each flight.

Plus the accessories required, eg the controller, spare batteries and camera.

So how to carry it comfortably and safely on a bike? Some sort of large messenger bag, or a rucksack? Or some way of attaching it to a rack?

It would need something to protect it from getting bashed, ie some sort of padding. And preferably some sort of cover to keep the rain off.

Comment: A larger stout cardboard box on your rear carrier, with packing as appropriate.  Don't drop the bike, and strap the box down so it doesn't fly off.    Carry your accessories around it, or in your pack.

Comment: I would be tempted to look at a back pack option, so you can go places without the bike, e.g. ride somewhere then walk to the top of the hill or edge of the beach.  Thinking something along the lines of what photographers with a million lenses use.

Comment: Messenger bags are a bad way to carry anything heavy, especially on a bike where gravity is trying to make them swing down off your back.

Comment: A quadcopter is fairly lightweight (unless you are carrying loads of extra batteries). Its more the shape that makes it awkward.

Comment: Back pack would be my vote, rain cover if necessary. There are even companies that make backpacks specifically for this purpose. You spent all that money on the 'copter why skimp on means of transporting it?

Comment: @vclaw spare batteries and other heavy accessories would be best in a pannier

Answer (score 2):

I don't own quadcopters nor fly them, but for something of that price, a [**hard case**, filled with foam cut to size](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=drone%20case&iar=images&iax=1&ia=images), seems to me the obvious choice.

As for how to mount the case on the bike, I'd probably make an S-shaped hanger

```
_
 |
 |_|
```

to hang it off the back rack—probably on the right side, so I could still lay the bike down on the left side. Or put it in a handlebar basket or a pannier, if you can get one big enough.

If the case-and-contents is small enough and light enough, you can alternatively carry it in a backpack. For any significant weight, getting the bike to do the carrying is preferred.